# Can I improve "free" affiliations during character burning?

Tags: character-creation, burning-wheel

Some character traits give you a free affiliation, usually at 1D.

**Can I spend resource points to improve this freebie affiliation during character burning?**

For example, nobles get a freebie affiliation from Mark of Privilege. If I want to be one of the more prominent members of an exceptionally big and powerful house, can I improve my house affiliation to 2D?

**How many resource points would it cost?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Affiliation traits stack with each other and affiliations you buy](https://forums.burningwheel.com/t/stacking-nobility-affiliations-from-sworn-homage-and-mark-of-privilege/12276)

As such, if you buy a 1D Affiliation with nobility, the 1D from Mark of Privilege increases it to 2D. The 1D you pay for will cost you 10rps, because you're only *buying* 1D of affiliation—you're not buying 2D, or "upgrading" for 25rps with a 10rps discount for the 1D from Mark of Privilege, or something like that, just the 1D is being bought and paid for.

And remember that your starting Resources is based on the rps *spent*, so that 1D from Mark of Privilege doesn't count, and the "upgrade" only costing you 10rps can actually sometimes be a bit of a disadvantage compared to some kind of "upgrade math" that would say it costs 25rps (for 2D) − 10rps (for the "free" 1D) = 15rps.

Comment: I don't see the thread talking about affiliations that one buys with resource points, or about improving trait-granted affiliations with resource points. Any source for that?

Comment: @Thanuir No, but the discussion of stacking intersects naturally with the general BW principle that you only get what extra you pay for and only pay for what extra you get. Buying a 1D noble affiliation costs 10rps, and due to stacking, that's the most direct route to 1D (bought) + 1D (Mark of Privilege).